# Docker tmux issue

Tags: docker, prompt, tmux

I installed Parrot OS as a docker container and when I run tmux in it, the **prompt string** changes. It acts like an eyesore to an OCD person. I don't really know what the issue could be called exactly so can't mention the term, sorry for that.

[image]

In the image, they are two different containers of Parrot OS, with tmux running in upper container. I think the issue is understandable from the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because tmux is not aware that your terminal support UTF-8. Either:

- Add the `-u` flag to tmux (`tmux -u new` or `tmux -u attach`); or
- Make sure your system is in a UTF-8 locale and the environment variables are set correctly (`LANG`, `LC_ALL` and so on).