# Tmux running inside Docker container prints ^[[A, ^[[B, ^[[C, and ^[[D for arrow keys

Tags: docker, tmux

I have a docker container running on an ubuntu machine; however, when I run tmux inside that docker container, there are several symptoms:

1. the prompt string changes to `$`  (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302985/docker-tmux-issue) question)
2. the up and down arrow keys print `^[[A` and `^[[B` instead of scrolling through command history
3. the tab key does not do auto-completion as expected, but rather prints an actual tab.

Colors are displaying fine.

My `.tmux.conf` contains the following: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

My environment variables (within the docker container) should be set correctly.
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
`$TERM='screen-256color'`

I have tried `tmux -u new`, as in the question linked above.

I am ssh-ing into this ubuntu machine via my local machine's terminal.

Comment: why do you need tmux in a docker container?

Comment: Is this container running with `-t`? If not it won't allocate a pty.

Comment: @TheFool I would like to have multiple interactive sessions in the same docker environment. The only alternative I can think of is running a new container for each session, and that is a lot of overhead.

Comment: @NickODell: yes, I am running with `-t`!

Comment: @Erica As an alternative, you can use `docker exec -it <container name> bash` for that purpose. Doesn't create a new container - just a process within the existing container.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for the suggestion. I would still prefer having tmux within the docker container, so then I could open a new window without having to type any other commands.

Comment: This issue actually exists also on some containers when using sh. I cant name one from the top of my head but I have had this situation serveral times when doing exec with `sh` as command. And I definitely used `-ti`.

Comment: What Dockerfile was used to produce the image? I tried an Ubuntu based container and it was able to run tmux.